# Filtering by trait matching partial names as well as full in Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, string-matching, traits, test-explorer

I'm using Test Explorer to filter tests.  In the search box, you can use traits to pull out tests for certan categories.  For example:

```
Trait:"Awesome"
```

Will filter just the tests with the test category of "Awesome".

However, we've now, say, built tests with the category of "Awesomeness" as well.

So to get those, you do:

```
Trait:"Awesomeness"
```

However, now when you use:

`"Trait:"Awesome"`, you now get tests with category of "Awesome" *as well as* "Awesomeness" as it's partially being matched - "**Awesome**ness".

Is there a way to specify tests with exact matching on the trait name, rather than the default partial matching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's impossible in the current version of Text Explorer. There is one workaround that you can use in order to filter out some unwanted results:

```
Trait:"Awesome" -Trait:"Awesomeness"
```

or even

```
Trait:"Awesome" -Trait:"Awesomen"
```